# How do you make local copies of jquery so that html page works correctly?

Tags: jquery, html, css

I'm using jquery for an html reports created by my application, and have these lines in the head of the html page.

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.9.1/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css" />
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.9.1.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.9.1/jquery-ui.js"></script>
```

but I didn't want the reports to have to rely on the jquery website, so I have made local copies of the file and changed the head of the html, as follows:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="../style/jquery//ui/1.9.1/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css" />
<script type="text/javascript" src="../style/jquery/jquery-1.9.1.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="../style/jquery//ui/1.9.1/jquery-ui.js"></script>
```

The links are okay, but page is not quite rendering correctly. Im using Acordian and it is mising the expand arrows on each header when I use my local copies of jquery

Comment: you have an extra `/` in a couple of places next to `jquery//`.. `src="../style/jquery//ui/1.9.1/jquery-ui.js">`

Comment: It sounds like the JQuery images folder is missing from your local copies.

Comment: A sidenote: I would suggest you to use `~/` instead of `../`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the only thing that is missing is the Arrows on the accordion (i.e. all the jquery code is working as expected) then I would guess that you are not copying the JQuery UI images folder locally along with the scripts.

As discussed in the commets the images folder is not allowing a listing so retrieving the images programmatically is not really trivial.

The methods I can think of to resolve this are:

- Manually download the Jquery UI package yourself to keep as a local artifact
- Modify the css file to update the urls to point to the cdn urls
- Modify the css manually yourself and keep this file as an artifact

Comment: I think you have it, but the images folder is not visible I can see http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.9.1/themes/smoothness/images/ui-bg_flat_75_ffffff_40x100.png but not http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.9.1/themes/smoothness/images folder. Had a look at the site but I cant see a 1.9.1 download ?

Comment: What I would suggest is  downloading the version/theme of Jquery UI yourself and keeping the images as a local artifact because they aren't allowing the listing of the images folder.

Comment: Thx @JustinM got it working, downloaded local package of Jquery UI (1.9.2) and download of Jquery (1.9.1), I didn't realize they were two seperate downloads.